# CSS/HTML Screen-size adaptive blocks/tiles

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I'm sure this has been asked before but I'm not sure of the terminology meaning my search results are not coming up with anything relevant.

I want to add some blocks of same-size content to my page and they should be organised in rows and columns, without a table, and adapt to larger and smaller screen sizes. Example in pictures: [image: large-width screen] [image: small-width screen]

Is there a simple cross-browser non JS way of doing this, which works without having to refresh the page (adaptive to changing screen size, i.e. on resize)?

Comment: Yeah, there's a few different ways. Your screenshots are bit confusing though, can you provide more information on what sizes you want for each screensize, so I can provide an adequate  example/answer?

Comment: Checkout Bootstrap ->  http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

The technique is called responsive web design.  You can create a four column page layout, with four div columns, each given a width of say 23% (adding up to just under 100%).  You will need to learn HTML and CSS and then responsive web design.  There is a lot of help online.

Images can also be made responsive by use of CSS as follows:

```html
img { 
          max-width: 100%;
          height: auto;
 }
```

You can also choose to learn the Bootstrap framework, which is an HTML framework to create responsive websites and could be used to create a responsive 4 column design.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adapt the image use: `object-fit: cover;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).